# Why I Have PyProjectException Exception?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I want to participate in Open Source [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi.git) on Github. I want to  translate framework's documents. I cloned repo, and then wanted to configure environment with poetry. But I face up with problem. When I enter `poetry install` in PowerShell in the directory with project.tomlI receive an error:

```
PS C:\\User\\workspace\\FastAPI\\fastapi\> poetry install
```

PyProjectException

```
\[tool.poetry\] section not found in C:/User/workspace/FastAPI/fastapi/pyproject.toml

at \~.poetry\\lib\\poetry_vendor\\py3.10\\poetry\\core\\pyproject\\toml.py:56 in poetry_config
52│     def poetry_config(self):  # type: () -\> Optional\[TOMLDocument\]
53│         if self.\_poetry_config is None:
54│             self.\_poetry_config = self.data.get("tool", {}).get("poetry")
55│             if self.\_poetry_config is None:
→ 56│                 raise PyProjectException(
57│                     "\[tool.poetry\] section not found in {}".format(self.\_file)
58│                 )
59│         return self.\_poetry_config
60│
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/contributing/